# How do I align a jQuery slider and an input field on the same line?

Tags: jquery, input

I have been fiddling with aligning an input filed next to a slider and I have not have any luck.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lani/7hvwvnod/3/)

Please take a look at my fiddle.

```
<div id="slider1"></div>SME<input id="box2" class="form-control input-sm" data-cell="I2" data-format="0.00" size="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

`div` has `display:block;` by default it means it places in one line, however, there are a lot of solutions that you can solve your problem.

**display:block;**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hvwvnod/5/)

```
#slider1{
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**float:left;**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hvwvnod/5/)

```
#slider1{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

**Change html element(div to span)**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hvwvnod/8/)

```
<span id="slider1"></span>SME<input id="box2" class="form-control input-sm" data-cell="I2" data-format="0.00" size="4">

#slider1 {
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `float: left` to the slider's `div`

```
#slider1{
    width:100px;
    float: left;
}
```

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/7hvwvnod/4/).